# How can i integrate gmail to salesforce using apex

Tags: salesforce

I want to create a HTTPCallout in  salesforce apex to fetch all my contacts, emails ,etc. from gmail account without using any appexchange tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can make callouts to the Gmail Restful API via Apex.  This is very straightforward on the Apex side.  I would recommend using an external Auth Provider with a Named Credential, that way you don't need to write code to do the Authentication.

[apex_callouts_named_credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)

[Apex_Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Callouts)

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/